# Почему if нельзя напрямую присвоить константе?

Tags: javascript, функции, if, операторы

**Структура if**

```
if (условие) {
  инструкция1;
} else {
  инструкция2;
}
```

**Структура тернарного оператора**

```
условие ? выражениеЕслиTrue : выражениеЕслиFalse
```

**Структура функции**

```
function имя (параметр) {
  инструкция;
}
```

И if, и тернарный оператор — условные операторы, но во втором случае есть возможность присвоения константе напрямую.

Мы могли бы сказать, что if невозможно присвоить константе напрямую, поскольку внутри if, в отличие от тернарного оператора, находятся не выражения, а инструкции — они ничего не возвращают.

Но внутри функции также находятся инструкции и при этом, используя оператор return, мы можем вернуть значение и присвоить его константе.

Почему же мы не можем, используя return внутри if, присвоить значение константе?

Comment: Вы всё очень логично излагаете. Я предполагаю, что это шибка при разработке самого языка. Например, в языке scala `if` -- выражениe

Comment: Потому что if - это statement, а не expression. У него нет результата

Comment: @SergeiKirjanov, многие назовут весь JS одной большой ошибкой (и я даже частично буду среди них), но вот это уж точно не ошибка. JS не проектировался как ФП-язык, так что здесь `if` не то что не должен, а просто не может быть expression. Упомянутая вами Scala изначально создавалась как мультипарадигмальный язык с заявленной поддержкой ФП, так что там напротив `if` не может **не** быть expression.

Comment: Из Википедии: "Перед Бренданом Эйхом, нанятым в компанию Netscape 4 апреля 1995 года, была поставлена задача внедрить язык программирования Scheme или что-то похожее в браузер Netscape.", но "На синтаксис оказали влияние языки Си и Java, и, поскольку Java в то время было модным словом"; Вот так и живем.

Comment: @SergeiKirjanov, и?

Comment: Это просто ответ на вопрос в историческом контексте.

Comment: @SergeiKirjanov, на вопрос автора это вообще не отвечает ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ Для понимания, почему у if нет результата исполнения, крайне мало пригождается эта информация

Comment: Вполне, это "почему высшго порядка", не "как работает", а "почему так сделали": в js if нельзя напрямую присвоить константе, потому что это поведение содрали с модной тогда Java; в Java из C, а почему в C, мне и самому интересно.

Comment: @SergeiKirjanov, откуда у вас такая тяга к выражениям там, где в этом нет нужды? :) А про С объясню: он с самого начала следует одному простому правилу - быть максимально приближенным к машинным инструкциям. А теперь расскажите мне, пожалуйста, какой же результат нам возвращает `jmp` и в какой регистр она его пишет? :) Поэтому if как statement я нахожу крайне естественным и правильным

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`return` можно использовать только внутри функций, а `if` - не функция)

Честно: Не могу придумать реальный пример (кроме как "захотелось"), когда такой синтаксис был бы правда необходим. Более того, если и внутри `if`, и внутри `else` что-то очень длинное и сложное, вероятно, стоит завернуть каждый исход в отдельную функцию.

Варианты решения «Проблемы»:

```js
let x = 15;

const y = (x > 0) ? f(x) : g(x);

console.log(y);

/***/
function f(x) { // Что-то сложное и многострочное;
  return x * x + 10;
}

function g(x) { // Что-то сложное и многострочное;
  return x * x * x;
}
```

```js
let x = 15;

const y = handler(x);

console.log(y);

/***/
function handler(x) {
  if(x > 0) {
    // что-то из нескольких строчек
    return x * x + 10;
  }
  
  // Если верхний return сработал, дело уже не дойдет сюда. Можно без else.
  return x * x * x;
}
```

Comment: С другой стороны, не могу придумать реальный пример, почему `if` должен не быть expression. Например, `eval("{1;2}")` и `(1,2)` вернут 2. Ждем do-expressions.

Answer (score 3):

К сожалению, таков синтаксис языка — expressions возвращают значения (в том числе вызов функции), statements (в том числе объединённые в блок) не возвращают значения, поэтому их результат нельзя присвоить.

Но скоро вы сможете делать что-то похожее, если это предложение войдёт в стандарт:

https://github.com/tc39/proposal-do-expressions